# Proper way to require libs in multiple files

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have two files - one with main code execution, and other just has a class in it.

For example:

File_1:

```
const _ = require('underscore'),
CoolClass = require('CoolClass');

_.map(//something)
```

Files_2:

```
const _ = require('underscore');

class CoolClass(){
  constructor(){
    _.map(//something);
  }
}
```

What's the proper way to require a library?

Should I require it in both files our should just require it in the main one and just pass it to constructor like:

```
let cool_stuff = new CoolClass(_);
```

Or should I pass it when I require it, so:

```
const _ = require('underscore')(_);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In Node, you'd always include it in each file independent of one another.

The loading library (whether Node's native `require` or something else) will usually cache the module to avoid actually reloading it multiple times from the file system.

You do this so you have a variable that references the library in each file.

You can technically do your second option, but you usually only do that if you have to import and then initialize in some way an object from that library, then you'd pass the initialized object.

Something like underscore which is just import-and-use, you would just require in each.

Comment: Thanks, I will stick to this then